# How do I get completed/cancelled flights from the Laminar Data API?

Tags: rest

I'm using the Laminar Data flights-by-airline API e.g.
https://api.laminardata.aero/v1/airlines/BAW/flights?user_key=

The response XML only ever contains flights with status scheduled, filed or airborne, never completed or cancelled. How do I get completed/cancelled flights via this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an optional URL parameter, `status`, that returns flights with a status of either airborne, cancelled, completed, filed or scheduled. See the active docs [here](https://developer.laminardata.aero/documentation/flightdata) for an example. Caveat, I work on the Laminar platform.